# Can't record current time-stamp for logging out

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

So I'm building a simple account system using PHP and mySQL. For some reason, I just can't get the current timestamp to record to the database when the user logs out.

Here's my logout script:

```
 <?php require 'connections.php'; ?>
    <?php
        session_start();

        //Setting Last Online Time
        $QueryLO = "UPDATE account SET A_LastOnline = date() WHERE AID='".$row['AID']."'";
        $con->query($QueryLO);

        unset($_SESSION["AID"]);
        unset($_SESSION["A_UserLevel"]);
        unset($_SESSION["A_Username"]);
        unset($_SESSION["A_Screenname"]);
        unset($_SESSION["A_FirstLogin"]);
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    ?>
```

The format of A_LastOnline is DateTime.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Here's the query working in the php portion of my login page.

```
    <?php require 'connections.php'; ?>
    <?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        $UN = $_POST['Username'];
        $PW = $_POST['Password'];

        $result = $con->query("select * from account where A_Username='$UN' AND A_Password='$PW'");

        $row  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["AID"] = $row['AID'];
        $_SESSION["A_UserLevel"] = $row['A_UserLevel'];
        $_SESSION["A_Username"] = $row['A_Username'];
        $_SESSION["A_Screenname"] = $row['A_Screenname'];
        $_SESSION["A_FirstLogin"] = $row['A_FirstLogin'];
        $_SESSION["A_RegisteredIP"] = $row['A_RegisteredIP'];
        $_SESSION["A_LatestIP"] = $row['A_LatestIP'];
        $_SESSION["A_LastOnline"] = $row['A_LastOnline'];

        echo $QueryLO = "UPDATE account SET A_LastOnline = NOW() WHERE AID='".$row['AID']."'";
        $con->query($QueryLO);

    }

?>
```

Edit: So my final solution was that:

```
$QueryLO = "UPDATE account SET A_LastOnline = date() WHERE AID='".$row['AID']."'";
```

Had to be changed to:

```
echo $QueryLO = "UPDATE account SET A_LastOnline = NOW() WHERE AID='".$_SESSION["AID"]."'";
```

To account for the session variable, since my $row wasn't set on this particular page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** Replace `date()` with `NOW()` in your query (or `CURDATE()` if you don't care about the specific time of day)

**2nd:** confirm that the query was run successfully by changing your query line to

```
if(!$con->query($QueryLO)){/*handle error here*/}
else{/*success: confinue to logout*/}
```

Comment: Like I said to John Conde, I still have no result. Is it an issue with DateTime? Do I have to include a format as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "no result".  `UPDATE` doesn't return matching rows. Which branch of my `if-else` does it go to?

Comment: Sorry I meant no result, as in the datetime did not change for the users A_LastOnline field.

Comment: ok. Which branch of my `if-else` does it go to? If the top one, you need to look into error details.  If the bottom one, your `$row['AID']` is not what you expect.

Comment: It runs through the bottom branch, but I have no idea what would be wrong with the account ID (AID). Any suggestions on how I could figure out whats wrong with that? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Then the problem is with `$row['AID']`.  We'll need to focus on where that value comes from, and what it is.

Comment: Hmmm, when I place the query in my login page for example, it updates perfectly fine. That would suggest somethings up with my logout script itself no? Would you like me to post my login code for comparison?

Comment: The query itself is fine, so I'm not surprised that it works elsewhere. The problem is the value you plug into it. Look into how you assign a value to `$row['AID']`.  From the code you share, we have no way to know where it came from.

Comment: There's the login script. As you can see there I get $row['AID'] from the result query. AID is the Account ID which I gather along with the rest of the User's info if they have the correct username and password.

Comment: The logout script can't see `$row` from your login script but you saved it in the session. To access the ID in your logout script, use `$_SESSION['AID']` instead

Answer (score 0):

1. check your database field how it is defined like:
   A_LastOnline = date or datetime or timestamp

> if date then format is yyy-mm-dd. ex: $date = date('Y-m-d');
>   if datetime or timestamp then format is yyy-mm-dd. ex: $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

2. and then change the query in your code to below:

   ```
   //Setting Last Online Time

   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//or $date = date('Y-m-d');

   $QueryLO = "UPDATE account SET A_LastOnline = $date WHERE AID='".$row['AID']."'";
   $con->query($QueryLO);    
   ?>
   ```